# Refresh Knockout binding when the view model is updated with JSON data received from server

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout viewmodel which is updated with JSON data received from the server for each button click and would like to refresh the binding based on the changes to viewModel. I am using knockout mapping to convert the JSON to KO observables.

My question is the bindings are not refreshed when the viewmodel is updated on button click

The sample fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/saamisolutions/56Af6/4/)

JS:

```
    function getPlayersAsJSON(country) {
    var players = null;
    if (country === 'spain') {
        players = $('#spainText').val();
    } else if (country === 'swiss') {
        players = $('#swissText').val();
    }
    return players;
}

var viewModel = {
    players: ko.observableArray()
};

$(function () {
    $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
        var playerDataJSON = getPlayersAsJSON($('#drpCountry').val());
        var playerData = ko.mapping.fromJSON(playerDataJSON);
        console.log(playerDataJSON);
        console.log(playerData);
        console.log(playerData());
        viewModel.players(playerDataJSON);
    });
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

HTML:

```
    <div>JSON Data for Spain
    <br/>
    <textArea id="spainText" rows="4" cols="50">[{"Name": "Nadal","Age": 28},{"Name": "Ferrer","Age": 32},{"Name": "Ferrer", "Age": 29}]</textArea>
    <br/>JSON Data for Swiss
    <br/>
    <textArea id="swissText" rows="4" cols="50">[{"Name": "Federer","Age": 32},{"Name": "Wawiranka", "Age": 28}]</textArea>
</div>
<br/>
<div>Select Country
    <br/>
    <select id="drpCountry">
        <option value="spain">spain</option>
        <option value="swiss">swiss</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" />
<br/>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: players">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.Age"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please let me know if you need more details

Comment: What is your question? What is not working?

Comment: Oh, I missed that important part. My question is the bindings are not refreshed when the viewmodel is updated on button click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is an array then `ko.mapping.fromJSON` will return a `ko.observableArray`.

So you need to write `playerData()` to unwrap the observable array otherwise you will end up your `players` observable array holding another observable array:

```
var playerData = ko.mapping.fromJSON(playerDataJSON);
viewModel.players(playerData()); //unwrap the playerData
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uD37f/).

As an alternative solution the mapping plugin supports to directly fill in an already existing observable arrays if the input is a JSON array, with the following syntax:

```
ko.mapping.fromJSON(playerDataJSON, {} /* empty options */, viewModel.players);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jh4ku/).